# What's the difference between two attribute-based routing approaches: HttpGet("") and Route("")?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, network-programming

I was looking for information about attribute-based routing and found that there are two different attributes one can use: `HttpGet("")` and `Route("")`. However, I can't find any information about what the difference is between them.

Does one of them exist in order to support old ASP versions, or this there a different reason?

P.S. My code might not be totally correct, because I have just started to learn ASP. If something is not clear, I will try to explain.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    // APPROACH 1
    [Route("api/books")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async List<Book> GetBooks() 
    {
        // Implementation
    }

    // APPROACH 2
    [HttpGet("api/books")]
    public async List<Book> GetBooks()
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`Route` is method unspecific, whereas `HttpGet` obviously implies that only GET requests will be accepted. Generally, you want to use the specific attributes: `HttpGet`, `HttpPost`, etc. `Route` should be used mostly on controllers to specify the base path for all actions in that controller. The one exception is if you're creating routes for exception handling / status code pages. Then, you should use `Route` on those actions, since requests via multiple methods could potentially be routed there.

Comment: Can I use `[HttpGet]` for `[Route("get/{query}", Name="getWithPagination")]`?

Comment: @Jack according to this [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-name) it's possible.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Chico? What do you think?

Comment: Is the code following code equivalent?

(1)
[Route("api/books")]
[HttpGet]

(2)
[HttpGet("api/books")]

because in (1) I also specificy the HTTP verb.