# ASP.NET Core Swagger error: "Fetch error Internal Server Error"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, swagger, openapi

I'm using all the latest Nuget Packages for ASP.NET Core Rest Server with Swagger

I cannot find how to fix the error described at the bottom (with code also). I tried:

- Adding `Route` attribute
- Adding a path to the `HttpGet` attribute
- Rename the parameter name

I always get the error described below:

> Internal Server Error...

with in the Debug Output Window:

> "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException:
> Ambiguous HTTP method for action -
> CommanDER.WebService.Controllers.GensetController.GetGensetsByMicrogridId
> (CommanDER.WebService). Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding
> for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0"

**Questions**

- Why do `Route` and `HttpGet` seems to offer the same things? => Answer found at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264139/whats-the-difference-between-two-attribute-based-routing-approaches-httpget) where I should use `HttpGet` for `GET` action.
- Why do both ways not seem to disambiguate the action?

Error:

[image]

> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action -
>
> CommanDER.WebService.Controllers.GensetController.GetGensetsByMicrogridId (CommanDER.WebService). Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0
>
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperations(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GeneratePaths(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwaggerDocumentWithoutFilters(String documentName, String host, String basePath)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwaggerAsync(String documentName, String host, String basePath)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using CommanDER.Data;
using CommanDER.Domain.ResourceDef;

namespace CommanDER.WebService.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class GensetController : ControllerBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get all resources of a Microgrid by the microgridId
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="microgridId"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Route("GetGensetsByMicrogridId/{microgridId}")]
        [HttpGet("GetGensetsByMicrogridId/{microgridId}")]
        public IEnumerable<Genset> GetGensetsByMicrogridId(int microgridId)
        {
            return _context.Gensets.Where(g => g.MicrogridId == microgridId).ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get Genset by it's ID
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Route("GetGensetById/{id}")]
        [HttpGet("GetGensetById/{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Genset>> GetGensetById(int id)
        {
            var genset = await _context.Gensets.FindAsync(id);

            if (genset == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return genset;
        }

        private readonly MicroReseauDbContext _context;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        public GensetController(MicroReseauDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get all gensets in the Database. Could be for more than one Microgrid (if applied).
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Route("All")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Genset>>> GetGensets()
        {
            return await _context.Gensets.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the [Route("xxx")] lines you should be fine. No need to use the "HttpGet" AND "Route"

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem:

I removed "Route" attribute and it fixed my problem.

It seems that both (HttpGet and Route) should not be used together. That's bad there is no message telling you that???? Grrrrrr!!!! I know that if I know what I do it wouldn't happen. But I still think it would be a nice validation, at least in Debug.